# Inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{(s^2 + 6s + 45)^2}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, laplace-transform

Inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{(s^2 + 6s + 45)^2}$. So we can see the determinant of the denominator is negative which means we have two conjugate roots. I then checked the book which gives a formula for such situation and tried to expand the fraction like that and tried to find the undetermined constants, but found the constants are all zero except one, which gives me the original form of the fraction.

Comment: Are you comfortable with complex numbers?  With Euler's identity, i.e. $e^{i x} = \cos x + i \sin x$?

Comment: If you do it correctly, you should end up with
$$
\frac 1{432}e^{-3t}(\sin(6t) - 6t \cos(6t))
$$
It is unlikely that your Laplace transform table includes anything of the form $t \cos(\beta t)$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, I know complex numbers.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks! Could you give me a link, if any, that includes the formula you mentioned. I still can't find it online.

Comment: I found the answer with [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+laplace+transform+1%2F(s%5E2+%2B+6s+%2B+45)%5E2)

Comment: @Hmm, I see. Thanks. But I still don't know how to calculate it by hand, like the simple versions of making it to the sum  of partial fractions.

Comment: outlined that below.  It is possible, and it is still possible using a table, but you'll need to rewrite things like
$$
e^{(3 + 6i)t} = e^{3t} [\cos(6t) + i \sin(6t)]
$$
and do a lot of cancelling out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are looking to do inverse Lapace transforms you are looking to "factor" the denominator like so...

$s^2 + 6s  + 45 = (s + 3)^2 + 36$

Not a true factoring, but complete the square.

Now I suggest you work backward and look at:

$\mathcal L \{\cos at\} = \frac {s}{s^2 + a^2}\\
\mathcal L \{e^{bt}\cos at\} = \frac {(s-b)}{(s-b)^2 + a^2}\\
\mathcal L \{\sin at\} = \frac {a}{s + a^2}\\
\mathcal L \{t f(t)\} = -\frac {d}{ds}\mathcal L \{f(t)\}$

Now you have to figure out how to get from

$\frac {1}{((s+3)^2 + 36)^2}$ to some combination of the above.

It is going to be something with the structure: $Ae^{-3t}\cos 6t + Be^{-3t}\sin 6t + Cte^{-3t}\cos 6t + Dte^{-3t}\sin 6t$

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite
$$
\frac 1{(s^2 + 6s + 45)^2} = 
\frac 1{((s + 3)^2 + 6^2)^2} = 
\frac 1{((s + 3) - 6i)^2((s + 3) + 6i)^2} = \\
\frac i{864} \frac 1{(s + 3 + 6i)} \\
\quad + \frac{-1}{144} \frac 1{(s + 3 + 6i)^2} \\
\quad - \frac{i}{864} \frac{1}{s + 3 - 6i}\\
\quad  - \frac{-1}{144} \frac 1{(s + 3 - 6i)^2}
$$